# How to type text in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, text

I'm looking to get the HTML page to type out some text when you visit said page, as if someone behind the screen was using a keyboard even though no one is. I understand this may require the use of the `<script>` tag.

What I have so far

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Happy Valentine</title>
        <style type="text/css">>
        body {
            background: black url("http://www.robodesign.ro/files/gallery/original/love_bites.jpg");
            background-repeat: repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
        <body onload=writetext() onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 2000)">
        <p align=center></p>
            <script language=JavaScript>
            msg = new Array(); //strings written in screen
            msg[0] = "Blah with html";
            text1 = ""; //the same as text2, only the last character is highlighted.
            text2 = ""; //current string, which will be written.
            count = 0; //char index in string text
            count2 = 0; //number of strings
            text = msg[0].split(""); //text - string written
            function writetext() { //show strings above on screen
                text1 = text2 + "<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + text[count] + "</font>";
                text2 += text[count];
                document.all["nothing"].innerHTML = text1; //where to write
                if (count < text.length-1){
                    count++;
                    setTimeout('writetext()', 34);
                    }
                else { //if this string is written, get the new string
                    count = 0;
                    if (count2 != 14) { //write 14 strings
                        count2++;
                        text2 += ""; //a new line
                        text = eval('msg['+count2+'].split("")') //get the new string to text
                        setTimeout('writetext()', 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            </script>
            <script language="JavaScript">
                function disableselect(e){
                    return false
                }
                function reEnable(){
                    return true
                }
                //if IE4+
                document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false")
                document.oncontextmenu=new Function ("return false")
                //if NS6
                if (window.sidebar){
                    document.onmousedown=disableselect
                    document.onclick=reEnable
                }
            </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

For whatever reason, I can't get this to work and I can't establish why ._. I've been looking it over for a good few hours now.

Comment: No need to edit your question, look at the answer @BrandonConley

Comment: I looked at your answer, but it doesn't achieve the full effect I'm aiming for like the code above.

Comment: What effect are you aming for?

Comment: typing onload ?

Comment: Yup, I just don't understand where i went wrong with it :/

Comment: I'm working on it right now.

Comment: To add more lines I essentially add msg[1] = "" msg[2] = "" and so on

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade I guess because it was just a link-only answer.

Comment: I tweaked your original code to work. @BrandonConley

Comment: See my answer for the working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code have some errors for example:

```
setTimeout(writetext,34)
//count =0 inside the function make an non ending loop
```

i modified your code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Happy Valentine</title>
  <script>
    msg1 = "Blah blah with html";
    msg2 = " Blah with html";
    count = 0;
    count2 = 0;
    function writetext() {
      if (count < msg1.length){
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += msg1.charAt(count);
        count++;
        setTimeout(writetext, 50);
      }
      else {
        if (count2 < 14){
          document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += msg2.charAt(count2);
          count2++;
          setTimeout(writetext, 50);
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="writetext()">Click me</button>
  <p id="text"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code and adapt it to what you need.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Typewriter</h1>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.  af \n af';
var speed = 50;
document.onload=typeWriter()
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i).replace("\n","<br>");
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And your original code, tweaked to work:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Happy Valentine</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: black url("http://www.robodesign.ro/files/gallery/original/love_bites.jpg");
            background-repeat: repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
        <body onload=writetext() onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 2000)">
        <p align=center id="printto"></p>
            <script>
            msg = new Array(); //strings written in screen
            msg[0] = "Blah with html \n Nextline";
            text1 = ""; //the same as text2, only the last character is highlighted.
            text2 = ""; //current string, which will be written.
            count = 0; //char index in string text
            count2 = 0; //number of strings
            text = msg[0].split(""); //text - string written
            function writetext() { //show strings above on screen
                text1 = text2 + "<font color='#FFFFFF'>" + text[count] + "</font>";
                text2 += text[count];
                document.getElementById("printto").innerHTML = text1.replace("\n","<br>"/*seamles neqlining*/); //where to write
                if (count < text.length-1){
                    count++;
                    setTimeout('writetext()', 34);
                    }
                else { //if this string is written, get the new string
                    count = 0;
                    if (count2 != 14) { //write 14 strings
                        count2++;
                        text2 += ""; //a new line
                        text = eval('msg['+count2+'].split("")') //get the new string to text
                        setTimeout('writetext()', 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            </script>
            <script>
                function disableselect(e){
                    return false
                }
                function reEnable(){
                    return true
                }
                //if IE4+
                document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false")
                document.oncontextmenu=new Function ("return false")
                //if NS6
                if (window.sidebar){
                    document.onmousedown=disableselect
                    document.onclick=reEnable
                }
            </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I forgot all about \n xD

Comment: The "tweaked" code still contains errors that prevent it from working as expected, e.g. the two `onload` attributes in the body tag.